# SSL Session resumption and IDs

Tags: cryptography, encryption, tls

Some sites, as seen in the [report for www.mbank.com.pl](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html?d=www.mbank.com.pl&s=193.41.230.81) [ssllabs.com] or [report for aliorbank.pl](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html?d=aliorbank.pl&s=195.182.52.101) [ssllabs.com] do not support "Session resumption", either because IDs are assigned but not accepted (first case) or because IDs are empty (second case).

It's not related to secure renegotiation, as visible in [report for poczta.interia.pl](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html?d=poczta.interia.pl) [ssllabs.com] where the session resumption is unavailable while renegotiation is performed in secure manner.

Question:
Why it's in red? Is it a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not supporting session resumption is *not* a security vulnerability; but it implies a new handshake per connection, which can increase latency (a full handshake implies more roundtrips than a resumed session) and CPU cost (mostly on the server, with the common RSA key exchange).

The first server is somewhat discourteous, in that it returns a non-empty session ID that it will refuse anyway; what the second server does (returning an empty ID) is what the [SSL/TLS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246) recommends. Yet returning a non-empty session ID for an unresumable session is not a true bug.

Presumably, `ssllabs.com` uses the red color here because it is relatively uncommon to deactivate session resumption -- and thus this may be a "configuration bug" worth reporting (although the red might veer a bit too much on the scary).

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas already pointed out, disabling session resumption is not a vulnerability. Session resumption is actually a performance feature to reduce latency of subsequent requests to the same server made within a short span of time.

There is a reason some servers return a session ID then refuse to accept it (which this test is complaining about). I recall this behavior being a workaround for at least one browser that failed to properly handle a lack of a session ID [citation needed].

As for your connection, disabling session resumption can actually improve security. Session resumption can harm the effectiveness of [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) by continuing to reuse sessions.

In some cases a badly configured server can completely negate all the benefits of forward secrecy by configuring their server to store resumption details for a long period of time. [RFC4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346) suggests a 24 hour upper limit on a sessions lifetime, however it is still suggested that browsers accept whatever lifetime the server uses.